# Classifying based on irregular number of features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

Ok, so I am trying to classify a rather large data set where the training set has some peculiar issues...

- There are a different number of features available for each row. For example, I might have 10 data points to work with for one prediction and only 3 for another. I would want to somehow null the empty data points because they aren't necessarily 0. We just don't have the data.
- Each feature is a triplet of numbers (A,B,C), (A1,B1,C1), (A2,B2,C2). Should I separate these into individual features or is there a way to keep them grouped?
- There are a few features/variables which all rows will have.

Is there preferred methodology?

```
| Y | v0        | v1        | v2      | v3     | v4 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8 | v9 | A | B | C  |
|---|-----------|-----------|---------|--------|----|----|----|----|----|----|---|---|----|
| A | 15,0,7    | 18,0,2    | 23,0,0  | 21,0,3 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 1 | 0 | 5  |
| B | 15,.05,12 | 14,.05,12 | 9,.3,45 |        |    |    |    |    |    |    | 2 | 2 | 12 |
| A | 18,0,2    | 23,.03,0  |         |        |    |    |    |    |    |    | 0 | 1 | 3  |
| A | 23,0,0    | 18,0.07,2 | 15,0,7  |        |    |    |    |    |    |    | 3 | 1 | 1  |
| C | 4,.08,212 |           |         |        |    |    |    |    |    |    | 6 | 4 | 4  |
| B | 14,.05,12 | 9,.3,45   |         |        |    |    |    |    |    |    | 1 | 3 | 9  |
```

Comment: This might well depend on context; can you add some?  Quite possibly [tag:multi-instance-learning] is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is:

- To use a learning algorithm which can handle [missing values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data). You should be careful about whether these missing values occur randomly or not though, as they could cause the model to be biased.
- Triplets can be separated into individual features, there's no simple way to process them differently anyway.